Routing local resources through wireguard VPN on Oracle Cloud
I am currently trying to setup wireguard vpn on Oracle to access my local resources behind a CGNAT network.
Here's my setup:
Network Topology

Oracle Instance:
wg0.conf:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <secret>
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 192.168.7.1/24, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::11/112
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/helper/add-nat-routing.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/helper/remove-nat-routing.sh

[Peer]
PublicKey = <secret>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.2/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::12/128, 10.101.7.0/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = <secret>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.3/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::13/128

add-nat-routing.sh:
#!/bin/bash
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
IPT6="/sbin/ip6tables"

IN_FACE="enp0s6"                   # NIC connected to the internet
WG_FACE="wg0"                    # WG NIC
SUB_NET="192.168.7.0/24"          # WG IPv4 sub/net aka CIDR
WG_PORT="51820"                  # WG udp port
SUB_NET_6="fd42:42:42::/64"      # WG IPv6 sub/net
IPV6_ADDR="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::12"
IPV6_ADDR1="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::13"

## IPv4 ##
$IPT -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD 1 -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD 1 -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT 1 -i $IN_FACE -p udp --dport $WG_PORT -j ACCEPT

# port forwarding

## Plex
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i enp0s6 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 32400 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s6 -p tcp --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.7.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 32400 -d 192.168.7.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.7.1

## IPv6 (Uncomment) ##
killall dhclient # kill dhcp clients
### ipv6 client 1
ip -6 neigh add proxy $IPV6_ADDR dev $IN_FACE
ip -6 addr del $IPV6_ADDR dev $IN_FACE

### ipv6 client 2
ip -6 neigh add proxy $IPV6_ADDR1 dev $IN_FACE
ip -6 addr del $IPV6_ADDR1 dev $IN_FACE

#$IPT6 -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s $SUB_NET_6 -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT6 -I INPUT 1 -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -I FORWARD 1 -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -I FORWARD 1 -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT

remove-nat-routing.sh:
#!/bin/bash
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
IPT6="/sbin/ip6tables"

IN_FACE="enp0s6"                   # NIC connected to the internet
WG_FACE="wg0"                    # WG NIC
SUB_NET="192.168.7.0/24"          # WG IPv4 sub/net aka CIDR
WG_PORT="51820"                  # WG udp port
SUB_NET_6="fd42:42:42::/64"      # WG IPv6 sub/net
IPV6_ADDR="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::12"
IPV6_ADDR1="aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::13"

# IPv4 rules #
$IPT -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -D INPUT -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -D FORWARD -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -D FORWARD -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT -D INPUT -i $IN_FACE -p udp --dport $WG_PORT -j ACCEPT

# port forwading
## Plex
sudo iptables -D FORWARD -i enp0s6 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 32400 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i enp0s6 -p tcp --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.7.2
sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 32400 -d 192.168.7.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.7.1

# IPv6 rules (uncomment) #
ip -6 neigh del proxy $IPV6_ADDR dev $IN_FACE
ip -6 neigh del proxy $IPV6_ADDR1 dev $IN_FACE
#$IPT6 -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s $SUB_NET_6 -o $IN_FACE -j MASQUERADE
$IPT6 -D INPUT -i $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -D FORWARD -i $IN_FACE -o $WG_FACE -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -D FORWARD -i $WG_FACE -o $IN_FACE -j ACCEPT

routing table:
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.251 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s6 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.251 metric 100
10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.251 metric 100
10.101.7.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.251 metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp0s6 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.251 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-29316d3b9da8 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.7.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.1


Windows machine:
Enable Routing and Remote Access service
Enable packet forwarding:
Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled

wg0.conf:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = YAzh9/NKd1oT3bu1k4oldamUhP2BxKItvM+xkDkmwUs=
Address = 192.168.7.2/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::12/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2001:4860:4860::8888

[Peer]
PublicKey = CH+TZnuK3VNnXFwKuezsynA9HqXbRKJJJe2g8/OIhnA=
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.0/24
Endpoint = <cloud_public_ip>:51820

routing table:
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.101.7.254     10.101.7.142     25
       10.101.7.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.101.7.142    281
     10.101.7.142  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.101.7.142    281
     10.101.7.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.101.7.142    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      172.21.32.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.21.32.1   5256
      172.21.32.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.21.32.1   5256
    172.21.47.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.21.32.1   5256
      192.168.7.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.7.2      5
      192.168.7.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.7.2    261
    192.168.7.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.7.2    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.101.7.142    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.21.32.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.101.7.142    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.21.32.1   5256
===========================================================================


From the cloud instance, I can ping my PC host at 10.101.7.142 and 192.168.7.2. From my Windows PC, I can ping my Oracle cloud instance at 192.168.7.1 as usual. But I cannot ping my phone at 10.101.7.59 from the cloud instance unless I set the gateway on my phone as 10.101.7.142 which holds the routing table for 192.168.7.0/24. This is as expected I would say, since my router at 10.101.7.254 has no idea how to route to the 192.168.7.0/24 network.
Things gets interesting as I tried to use a hyperv Ubuntu VM inside my windows host to initiate the VPN connection instead, and add a routing rule for 192.168.7.0 forwarding to that VM. Now from the cloud instance, I can ping all of my devices in the 10.101.7.0/24 network. Here's the setup for that:
Oracle wg0.conf:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <secret>
ListenPort = 51820
Address = 192.168.7.1/24, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::11/112
PostUp = /etc/wireguard/helper/add-nat-routing.sh
PostDown = /etc/wireguard/helper/remove-nat-routing.sh

[Peer]
PublicKey = <secret>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.2/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::12/128

[Peer] # the ubuntu vm
PublicKey = <secret>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.3/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::13/128, 10.101.7.0/24

Ubuntu VM wg0.conf:
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.7.3/32, aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::13/128
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 2606:4700:4700::1111, 2001:4860:4860::8888
PrivateKey = MNDrU/wYHUW+aeJRP5AeC+P72IXHahoD7OdiCRi1HVQ=

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 192.168.7.0/24
Endpoint = <cloud_public_ip>:51820
PublicKey = CH+TZnuK3VNnXFwKuezsynA9HqXbRKJJJe2g8/OIhnA=
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Windows host:
route add 192.168.7.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.21.34.107

where 172.21.34.107 is the ip of my Ubuntu VM in the 172.21.32.0/20 hyperv network.
My question is how can I get it work just by using my Windows host, and why does the latter solution where I use the Ubuntu VM works, how does my phone know how to route back that traffic to the 192.168.7.0/24 network without having the routing table for that in the router or setting the gateway to my Windows PC. Thanks in advance for your help.

As I suspected, the 172.21.32.0/20 hyperv network effectively did an SNAT to 10.101.7.0/24 network. I solved the problem by adding a NetNat inside Windows for the 192.168.7.0/24 network:
New-NetNat -Name wg0nat -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.7.0/24


Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

@help-info.de, thanks man, will definitely do.
